# Why is it not legal to access global non constant variable in constexpr non member function

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

```
int d = 1;
constexpr void add()
{
    d++;
}

int main()
{

}
```

GCC 7.1 will report errors below. The error message is very clear. The problem is that I don't see any explicit explanations in [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) to describe it's illegal.

Can someone explain which rules defined in spec this case violate?

```
main.cpp: In function 'constexpr void add()':

main.cpp:8:1: error: the value of 'd' is not usable in a constant expression

 }

 ^

main.cpp:4:5: note: 'int d' is not const

 int d = 1;

     ^
```

Comment: "there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression"

Comment: It seems break the rule #16(modification of an object, unless the object has non-volatile literal type and its lifetime began within the evaluation of the expression ). But if I change to constexpr void add()
{
    d = 2;
} then it can pass.

Comment: error message from clang looks clear, a constant expression cannot modify an object that is visible outside that expression. But I still can't find which rule it breaks in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions):

> A core constant expression is any expression that does not have any one of the following in any subexpression (ignoring unevaluated expressions such as the operand of sizeof or the right operand of builtin && when the left operand evaluates to false).
>
> ...
>
> 16) modification of an object, unless the object has non-volatile literal type and its lifetime began within the evaluation of the expression.

In your example, `d`'s lifetime began before `add` was evaluated - so any modification of `d` inside `add` is illegal. The example on the reference is specifically for incrementing, but this holds for all modifications.

Edit: Not quoting from the standard because as far as I'm aware, you've got to buy it...

Comment: I thought d's lifetime could be reason but GCC7.1 doesn't complain in this case, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4e544c05b187b03. If d = 2 is changed to d += 2, it will complain. Moreover, same code will always fails on clang, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d83921f7f0e871b

Answer (score 0):

The comments are good from a refer-you-to-the-standard perspective, but here hopefully a more intuitive explanation.

A `constexpr` function must be reducible to a constant expression at compile time. Since you are interacting with a regular, non-`const` `int` in the function, the compiler cannot determine what `d++` is under all circumstances. Consider the following case:

```
int d;
constexpr void add() {
    d++;
}

void foo() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    d = n;
    add();
}
```

In this case, the value of `d` inside `foo()` is indeterminate at compile time, and therefore, the constant expression that you are hoping `add()` to leave you with cannot be determined. I hope that helps.

Comment: That's not true. constexpr just implies if all the preconditions are satisfied, it will be evaluated at compilation time. Otherwisem it will run dynamically.